# Convert One Datetime format to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a `datetime2` format in my Database `2015-06-22 06:23:42.790`. I need to convert this into the following format `22/06/2015 06:23:42.790`.

Is it possible?

Comment: if the datatype is `datetime2`, then it's only been displayed with that format, it isn't really stored with a format

Comment: Use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), dtCol, 131)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME2 = '2015-06-22 06:23:42.790';

SELECT cast(convert(VARCHAR(10), cast(LEFT(@date, 10) AS DATE), 3) AS VARCHAR(10)) 
        + ' ' + substring(cast(@date AS VARCHAR(50)), 12, 12)
```

Query breakdown:

1. ***First part***: take first 10 characters from your datefield and then convert it to date style 3 (dd/mm/yyyy).
2. ***Second part***: Add a space between date and time.
3. ***Third part***: cast your datefield as varchar and extract the time which should   always start in the 12th position of your string.

Join them all together and there you have it! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to convert the database layout. Year Month Day is how SQL server shows the date because it ignores any international date formats.

I notice you want it as 22/06/2015 are you in the UK ? In the USA it would be 06/22/2015 Not such a problem because it's obvious that the 22 is the day. But if the date was 05/06/2015 how would sql or anyone know what day or month you're talking about.

So, get in to the habit of working in the ISO format year month day.

You don't mention what programming language. When reading data out of the database youd read it into a datetime variable. That will convert the date correctly into whatever locale your user is using. Different languages have different ways of getting the date into a datettime variable.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for display-use you can convert to varchar with FORMAT() function:

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE
(
    datevalue DATETIME2
)

INSERT INTO @tab VALUES(GETDATE())


SELECT  datevalue,
        FORMAT(datevalue,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff') as newformat
FROM    @tab
```